# Unable to get local issuer certificate in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, openssl

I am new to the node js.I am getting this error while running my node js code in local. Please help me in this.

```
(node:7532) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1048:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:628:8)
(node:7532) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:7532) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I tried some of the available solution on the internet, but so far any of them are working.
This are the things I have tried.

- npm set strict-ssl=false
- npm config set strict-ssl false
- export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0

Comment: Please read ask; in particular the part about providing a [mcve].